# Removing Sandbox Account from Settings (iOS 13.0 Issue)

Tags: ios, swift, sandbox

I have upgraded my iOS to version 13.0. When I try to sign out of the sandbox account the Settings app crashes. Is there any way to remove the sandbox account and reset it or clean up all of the developer settings without resetting the device?